# How to change the title of a Facebook's post?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I'm using the Graph API to share a player's progress to his Wall; doing it as an external application (i.e, not as one nested inside the Facebook's iframe).

```
$attachment = array('message' => "I have completed stage $level of the game with a score of $score!", 
                'description' => "Desc of the game.",
                'name' => "Name of game",
                'caption' => "caption",
                'type' => 'status',
                             'status_type' => 'app_created_story',
                'link' => "http://somehwere.com/somegame");

$result = $facebook->api("/me/feed/",'post', $attachment)) {
```

The post starts with "Test FB user **shared a link** via. Application".

How do I change "shared a link" to something else, such as "posted an update from"?

Comment: You can make custom actions via Facebook open Graph

Comment: Do you mean the actions field parameter, or the OpenGraph action types  being described at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/creating-action-types/ ?

Comment: Yes .. for ex you can create 'Extrakun cook a recepie on cookapp' ,You can try .. hope it helps